# How I can pass current Activity to a service?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

How I can pass `current Activity` to a `service` ?

I need to pass `Current Activity` to a `Class` that `Extends` from `Service` .

What can I do ?

Comment: `I need to pass Current Activity to a Class that Extends from Service .` why you need to pass?

Comment: I need to use in Service for show dialog !

Comment: Response the question for me with  Pop Up AlertDialog... for checked that .This is true .thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show `AlertDialog` from `Service` by setting layout type of alert `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` as:

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
dialog.show();
```

and add `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission to `AndroidManifest.xml`